# CSS Not Rendering with Apache, Django, and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, css, django, apache

I'm working dilligently to get Apache 2.4.7 to serve a Django 1.8.17 application using mod_wsgi 4.5.15 with Python 3.5.3 as a virtual environment. This is the only virtual environment I have on the machine (Linux Mint 17.3).

All the dynamic content is coming through, but not all of the static content.

- I have several apps in my project and when I run collectstatic, it appears to be placing them all in a single correct location like it's supposed to. I checked them all and they are all there.
- I have given all files in that location permissions using "sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ... ".
- I have modified my Apache virtual host file to add alias's that point to my "media" and "static" directories using absolute paths.
- When that didn't work, I tinkered with settings.py and tried changing the dynamic code that determines STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS to absolute paths (that didn't work either, I changed them back)

> ```
> home/magic-rat/
> |
> |_____+virtualenvs
> |               |
> |               |+ektropy_project
> |                        |
> |                        |+lib
> |                           |
> |                           |+python3.5
> |                                |
> |                                |+site_packages
> |
> |_____+ektropy_project   
>                   |
>                   |-manage.py
>                   |+static (for pinax)
>                   |        |
>                   |        |+dist
>                   |        |+src
>                   |
>                   |+ektropy_project
>                            |
>                            |-wsgi.py
>                            |
>                            |+site_media
>                                  |
>                                  |+media
>                 STATIC HERE=>    |+static 
>                                     |
>                                     |+admin
>                                     |+bootstrap
>                                     |+css 
>                                     |+fonts
>                                     |+js
>                                     |+pinax
> ```

Apache virtualhost:

```
Alias /media /home/magic-rat/ektropy_project/ektropy_project/site_media/media
<Directory /home/magic-rat/ektropy_project/ektropy_project/site_media/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /static /home/magic-rat/ektropy_project/ektropy_project/site_media/static
<Directory /home/magic-rat/ektropy_project/ektropy_project/site_media/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess ektropy_project python-home=/home/magic-rat/virtualenvs/ektropy_project python-path=/home/magic-rat/ektropy_project
WSGIProcessGroup ektropy_project
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/magic-rat/ektropy_project/ektropy_project/wsgi.py

<Directory /home/magic-rat/ektropy_project/ektropy_project>
    <Files wsgi.py>
       Require all granted
    </Files>
 </Directory>
```

Pertinent Parts Of Settings.py:

```
    import os

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir))
PACKAGE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
BASE_DIR = PACKAGE_ROOT

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "site_media", "media")

MEDIA_URL = "/site_media/media/"

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "site_media", "static")

STATIC_URL = "/site_media/static/"

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static", "dist"),
]

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "ektropy_project.urls"

WSGI_APPLICATION = "ektropy_project.wsgi.application"
```

I'm really at a loss.

"django.contrib.staticfiles", is in "INSTALLED_APPS"

There are no errors thrown.  Apache error log is clean.  Apache just can't see the static content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `chown -R www-data:www-data` is not really what you want. It can still be whatever user it was before. The key is that all directories down to the directory where static files are have permissions `o+rx`, and the files themselves are `o+r`. If there is some directory anywhere in the hierarchy down to that point with the incorrect permissions, the Apache user will not be able to read anything out of the directory.

The thing that looks wrong though is:

```
MEDIA_URL = "/site_media/media/"
STATIC_URL = "/site_media/static/"
```

These don't match what is in the Apache configuration.

Either change those to:

```
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
```

or change the Apache configuration to:

```
Alias /site_media/media /home/magic-rat/ektropy_project/ektropy_project/site_media/media
<Directory /home/magic-rat/ektropy_project/ektropy_project/site_media/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /site_media/static /home/magic-rat/ektropy_project/ektropy_project/site_media/static
<Directory /home/magic-rat/ektropy_project/ektropy_project/site_media/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The first argument to `Alias` directive should match `MEDIA_URL` and `STATIC_URL`.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you so much, Graham.  I'm up and running now.